# .htaccess: LogLevel not allowed here

Tags: apache

I want to see how my .htaccess file works. I put a LogLevel directive in it,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
...
```

But then in my httpd log file, I see:

```
.htaccess: LogLevel not allowed here
```

How do I debug my .htaccess file?

Thanks.

Comment: In the [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel), the concept of which directives will work in which files is called "Context". The `LogLevel` directive has `Context: server config, virtual host, directory`, notably not `Context: .htaccess`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Log level will not work in .htacesss file put this config in apache config file.

The syntax you are trying, i assume is for apache 2.4 put it as

```
LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace4
```