# Best way to remove public and index.php from Laravel 5 URLS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

As i am new to laravel, i have installed a fresh copy, give necessary permissions and run the application everything is good.
Now i have create a virtual host in apache to remove the public, which is also working fine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mobileapp

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mobileapp/public
<Directory "/var/www/html/mobileapp/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mobileapp_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mobileapp_access.log combined
```

Now the site can access locally through http://mobileapp/index.php/pages, but not working if i remove index.php from url (http://mobileapp/pages).
My .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]           # <----- Tested not working
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]             # <----- neither this one
```

I have also enable mode_rewrite. Can any one tell me what is the best and easy way to ride on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this front controller rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/|$) - [L,NC]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it give this error in log file: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Comment: ok check updated answer and update your question if you more rules in your htaccess

Comment: yeah, it's working fine now.. Thanks. Actually i have placed two .htaccess files one on root directory while the other in public directory. Now i remove the root one (because the DocumentRoot is Public direcotry) and secondly change .htaccess to old one, working fine... but your one also work on the worst situation, thanks man... :)

Answer (score 1):

To debug rewrites, add the following to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Then you can try different regular expressions for your RewriteRules to see what happens.  I would try something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php(.*)$ http://mobileapp/$1 [L]
```

Remember that for the `RewriteRule` to apply, the `RewriteCond` lines need to be satisfied first.  In your case, you are doing conditions of `!-d` and `!-f`, so that maybe your issue.

Comment: it gives me this error in log file: Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Strange, it comes with mod_rewrite:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: But that has been replaced with another mechanism in apache 2.4: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging  so you just need to set LogLevel

Comment: ok, i have placed this new method (LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3) and give me this...LogLevel not allowed here

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054592/htaccess-loglevel-not-allowed-here

Comment: same message returned: LogLevel not allowed here

Comment: Did you move it out from your .htaccess and into your http conf?

Answer (score 0):

I just rename `server.php` to `index.php` and it works